# Find correct bracket sequence, build from two parts of original bracket sequence

Tags: algorithm

Consider bracket sequences that consist only of '(' and ')'. Let S be any bracket sequence (not necessarily correct) with n items: S[1:n].
I need to write an algorithm, that will find such a number i (from 1 to n, if there is such a number), that S[(i+1):n]+S[1:i] is a correct bracket sequence. I also need this algorithm  to have O(n) operations.

It seems to me that I should use deque for this algorithm to pop the last element and push it in the beginning of a deque until a correct bracket sequence appears. But I can't find an efficient way to check, if the new sequence is correct - if I use a special counter, that increases each time '(' appears and decreases otherwise (note that a correct sequence must start with '('), then n operations (to check if the sequence is correct) will be done for each rearrangement of the last element in the beginning and algorithm as a whole takes O(n^2) operations, but I need linear time.

Should I really use deque or is there any other way to check the correctness of the sequence in the deque?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a single scan from left to right:

- Keep track of the nesting depth of the parentheses. So for example, after "((" it is 2, and after "(()))" it is -1.
- Keep track of the position at which this depth hit its minimum value during the scan. This will be the potential splitting point (after the bracket that caused the minimum depth).
- At the end of the scan verify that the depth has reached 0. If not, the input is not valid, otherwise return the splitting point.

By consequence, every input that has an equal number of opening and closing parentheses will have a solution.

Here is an implementation of this algorithm in an interactive JavaScript snippet. As you enter the input, the output is updated. It displays the rearranged parts of the input, separated by "...":

```js
function findSplit(s) {
    let start = 0;
    let depth = 0;
    let minDepth = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i] == ")") {
            depth--;
            if (depth < minDepth) {
                minDepth = depth;
                // restart
                start = i+1;
            }
        } else {
            depth++;
        }
    }
    if (depth != 0) return -1; // not valid
    return start;
}

// I/O handling
let input = document.querySelector("input");
let output = document.querySelector("pre");

function refresh() {
    let s = input.value;
    let start = findSplit(s);
    if (start == -1) output.textContent = "Invalid";
    else output.textContent = s.slice(start) + "..." + s.slice(0, start);
}
input.oninput = refresh;
refresh();
```

```html
<input value="())()(">
<pre></pre>
```